# Jquery Output Showed Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is My code:
**HTML Portion**

```
<form id="myform" action="whatever.php">
    <lable name="text">enter text</label>
    <input id="in" type="text" />
    <input id="in2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

**jquery Code:**

```
 (function($){
    $('#myform').on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
        var val = $(this).find('#in').val(); 
        $('ol.list').append('<li class="text-dark"><p>' + val + '.</p></li>');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Output:**

1.undefined.

2.undefined.

3.undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then element with id `in` is child element of `form` element not the `submit` button.

You need to do the following by getting to parent form element and then find inside that your element as your input element is not in the submit button :

```
var val = $(this).closest("form").find('#in').val();
```

`$(this).closest("form")` will select the form and then `find('#in')` will select the element with id `in` and then `val()` will get the value of it.

[See the working DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/19tsy8kr/)

Answer (score 1):

On your code `this` inside the callback function points to the button with id `#submit` not the form itself. 
You could just use the `submit` event, and your code will work fine

```js
(function($){
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        var val = $(this).find('#in').val(); 
        $('ol.list').append('<li class="text-dark"><p>' + val + '.</p></li>');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<ol class="list"></ol>
<form id="myform" action="whatever.php">
    <label name="text">enter text</label>
    <input id="in" type="text" />
    <input id="in2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```